# Will Firebase Storage charges me GB download for photoUrl that is stored in my document flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

After uploading my Photo to Firebase Storage, I saved the photoUrl in my document as a field. Now the question is if I call the document all fields including `photoUrl` will be received from Firestore. `photoUrl` field only has the URL.

Firebase Storage mentioned that they will charge for GB download for Firebase Storage. So If I only call the document that contains the `photoUrl`, will Firebase charge me for GB download for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understand, you upload the file in Cloud Storage and store the corresponding file URL (`photoUrl`) in a Firestore document. You probably use [`getDownloadURL()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/Reference/getDownloadURL.html) to get this URL after uploading the file.

Cloud Storage and Cloud Firestore are two different services, with two different billing "categories".

Therefore:

- If you only query a Firestore document containing a `photoUrl` field,
  you are NOT querying Cloud Storage. So the only cost will be the one
  corresponding to the Firestore document read.
- If you use this URL to download the file, then the only cost will be
  the one corresponding to the Cloud Storage file download. You are not
  querying Firestore, but just using a URL that you **previously** got
  from Firestore.